# Using a recursive assignment inside for loop in Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am trying to implement a fitness evaluation function in Verilog called Rosenbrock function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function). The issue I am facing is that if I use the following code it gives me a undefined state since there are 4 drivers to the wire `fitness_val`.

```
module test_module1 ( x, fitness);
    input   [4*2 -1:0]  x;  
    output  [1:0]   fitness;

    wire [1:0] x_i;
    wire [1:0] x_im1;
    wire [3:0] fitness_val;
    wire [3:0] a;
    wire [3:0] b;
    wire [1:0] x_array1 [3:0];
    
    genvar k;
        assign fitness = fitness_val;
        genvar j;
    
        generate
        for (j =0 ; j <4 ; j = j+1) begin
                assign x_array1[j] = x[2*j +: 2];
        end
                for (k=1; k<4; k=k+1) begin
                    assign x_i      = x_array1[k];
                    assign x_im1    = x_array1[k-1];
                    assign a = 100*(x_i[1:0] - x_im1[1:0])*(x_i[1:0] - x_im1[1:0]);
                    assign b = (1 - x_im1[1:0])*(1 - x_im1[1:0]);
                    assign fitness_val = fitness_val + a[2:1] + b[2:1];
            end
        endgenerate
endmodule

module tb_tm1();
  wire  [1:0]   fitness;
  wire [4*2-1:0] x_array;
  test_module1 tm1(x_array, fitness);
  assign x_array = 8'b11100100;
endmodule
```

However if I expand the for loop in this format, I get a valid output.

```
assign fitness_val = 100*(x_array1[1] - x_array1[0])*(x_array1[1] - x_array1[0]) + (1 - x_array1[0])*(1 - x_array1[0]) 
+ 100*(x_array1[2] - x_array1[1])*(x_array1[2] - x_array1[1]) + (1 - x_array1[1])*(1 - x_array1[1])
+ 100*(x_array1[3] - x_array1[2])*(x_array1[3] - x_array1[2]) + (1 - x_array1[2])*(1 - x_array1[2]);
```

Is there a way to implement this recursively in Verilog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assign` statements run concurrently; not sequentially. Generate loops are static unrolled during elaborations. When two `assign` statements drive different values to the same net, the result will be `x`.

To do sequential operations you will need to an `always` block.

Minimum change as follows (plus ANSI style header):

```
module test_module1 (
    input   [4*2 -1:0]  x,
    output  [1:0]   fitness ); // <-- ANSI style header

    reg  [1:0] x_i; // 'always' block assign 'reg' type
    reg  [1:0] x_im1;
    reg  [3:0] fitness_val;
    reg  [3:0] a;
    reg  [3:0] b;
    wire [1:0] x_array1 [3:0]; // 'assign' drives 'wire' type
    
    interger k; // index for loop in an always block
    genvar j;   // index for a generate loop
    assign fitness = fitness_val;
    
    generate
        for (j =0 ; j <4 ; j = j+1) begin
            assign x_array1[j] = x[2*j +: 2];
        end
    endgenerate
    
    always @* begin // @* is auto-sensitivity, use for combination logic
        fitness_val = 4'b0000; // initial value, otherwise it infers a latch
        for (k=1; k<4; k=k+1) begin
            x_i      = x_array1[k];
            x_im1    = x_array1[k-1];
            a = 100*(x_i[1:0] - x_im1[1:0])*(x_i[1:0] - x_im1[1:0]);
            b = (1 - x_im1[1:0])*(1 - x_im1[1:0]);
            fitness_val = fitness_val + a[2:1] + b[2:1];
        end
    end
endmodule
```

FYI: 4-bits is not enough to hold the value decimal 100. Do Do you want to make it bigger you did you intend the 100 to represent 4 in binary (`4'b0100`)?